# Intermittent RunAsync does not handle the function execution status FunctionsHostStoppingError causing Orchestrations to fail

Tags: azure-durable-functions, azure-deployment-slots

When I run orchestrations, some of them intermittently fail with an exception:

Exception while executing function: Orchestrator function 'x' failed: The activity function 'x' failed: "Failed to deserialize exception from TaskActivity: Unhandled exception while executing task: System.InvalidOperationException: RunAsync does not handle the function execution status FunctionsHostStoppingError.
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.TaskActivityShim.RunAsync(TaskContext context, String rawInput) in D:\a_work\1\s\src\WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask\Listener\TaskActivityShim.cs:line 124
at DurableTask.Core.TaskActivityDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass13_1.<b__2>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/DurableTask.Core/TaskActivityDispatcher.cs:line 178". See the function execution logs for additional details.

I've checked my app insights logs and I do not see any other underlying exceptions. What could be the issue?